# How can I hide a page for a specific language?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I think I may be missing something obvious here. I need to completely hide a specific page for a specific language. Blocks have a language visibility setting put pages and menus do not have anything similar and I haven't found a module for this functionality.

What is the best method for removing/hiding a page if a specific language is selected on a site? For example, About Us page shows for all languages except for German.

Comment: You can unpublish the page for a specific language if the Publishing status field is translatable.

Comment: Oh, right! I knew that but hadn't used it for a while. So obvious. Thank you!